# My .exe file cannot find its data files

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I used cx_freeze to create an .exe from my .py file. When I build the .exe file, my 2 data files are successfully included in the build folder, but when I run the .exe, the program cannot find the files.

My setup():

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


setup(name='pipermain',
    options={ 'build_exe':{'packages':[ 'tkinter','PIL' ],'include_files':   ['Transactions.csv', 'piper_copy.png' ]}},
    description='',
    executables= [Executable('pipermain.py')]
    )
```

I believe this to be a problem with the filepath in my .py code-- How to I write the correct filepath for my .exe to find the data files, no matter what computer the .exe is run on?

my file path was:

```
filepath = 'Transactions.csv'
```

because the data file was in my .py project folder. This worked successfully  when I ran the .py from PyCharm. But it couldn't locate the file in the build folder when I ran the .exe. Now, in an effort to make a file path that works with any system, it is:

```
filepath = os.path.abspath( 'Transactions.csv' )
```

The .exe only works if my filepath caters to my own system( /User/ethan/documents/project/transactions.csv). But if I send this .exe to others, the file path obviously won't work.

I have tried to make a variable file path by assigning, p = os.path.abspath( 'transactions.csv' ) to work on any system, but upon running the .exe I receive errors that the file does not exist. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By including the method:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)

    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)
```

and then reference any file paths using:

```
logopath =resource_path('Logo.jpg')
```

Should hopfully solve you issue

Comment: Dont forget to import os.path and sys

Comment: Hmm. I used your method and I am getting the same problem as I was when using os.path.abspath( 'Transactions.csv' ). When trying to access the csv from my .exe, the terminal gives me an error that says: The file /Users/ethan/Transactions.csv does not exist. This is true, because the file isn't in the "ethan" directory. It is in the build folder. I just can't seem to get it to call the build folder for its files.